# Dynamically hook in actionbar tablistener and actionmode for Android compatibility tablet app

Tags: android, compatibility, android-3.0-honeycomb, tablet

ok, there has to be a clean way to do this if you want to support the ActionBar on tablets for an app that runs on tablets and phones :-P

If I want to put it in my main FragmentActivity class, I can't add the "implements ActionTab.TabListener" to it because it'll fail w/ class not found on phones.
In code that uses ActionMode to make the ActionBar context sensitive

Almost seems like Google should have added dummy classes that do nothing so we can get it to compile/load cleanly on phones w/ the compatibility library :-(

What is everyone else doing if you want to use the ActionBar on Honeycomb tablets but you have to support phones as well?  Two entirely separate somewhat redundant classes that both call a Helper class w/ shared code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the standard compatibility package. Try [ActionBar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), it does this automatically for both phones and tablets.

Comment: Thanks, Nikolay.  ActionBar Sherlock looks like exactly what I want (and it really should be built-into the Android Compatibility Library)-:  No ActionMode support yet unfortunately but it looks like it's coming...

Answer (score 0):

I've put all my `ActionBar` code in a wrapper class, `ActionBarWrapper`, which I utilise in Honeycomb conditional code.

i.e.

```
if (MyApp.runningUnderHoneycomb) {
    ....
    ActionBarWrapper.doSomethingSuchAsRegisterNavigator(....)
}
```

where I utilise `values-v11\bools.xml` to set a variable to `true` which is defined to be `false` in `values\bools.xml`. I then assign my app's global variable `runningUnderHoneycomb` from the one in `bools.xml` as appropriate. This approach works for me.